# Rshiny conditional button/divs/table if button is pressed or rows selected from DT

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I can use conditionals in the UI for input fields without involving the server side. But when I try to do it for things like input_rows_selected or the state of a button; they don't work.

Below I have a couple of input fields set up with conditionals. The 2nd field depends on something in the first being selected. Then the first button depends on something in the second field being selected.

This is where it goes wrong.  The third button is supposed to only show up if rows are selected in the datatable. I have gotten it working if ONE row is selected, but not more than one row. And then the html and table below the third button is only supposed to be displayed once the third button is pressed. Currently the html is displayed, and the table doesn't work.

Ideas?  I am hoping to keep it as much as possible in the UI side. That way I can easily adapt the button hide/display functionality to various other chunks of code. But I'm not sure if that's possible.

**EDIT: UPDATED TO CURRENT CODE**
**EDIT 2: UPDATED TO FINAL WORKING CODE**

```
  if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  
  items <- data.frame(
    category = c("Room", "IceBreaker", "Activity", "Break"),
    group = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    className   = c ("red_point", "blue_point", "green_point", "purple_point"),
    content = c("Big Room", "Introductions", "Red Rover", "Lunch"),
    length = c(480, 60, 120, 90)
  )
  
  
  ui <- fluidPage(shinyUI(
    tagList(
      useShinyalert(),
      useShinyjs(),
      title = "Conditional Inputs",
      tabsetPanel(id = "mainTabset",
                  tabPanel(
                    title = "Wheeeeeee!",
                    class = "inputs",
                    column(
                      12,
                      
                      selectInput(
                        inputId = "input1",
                        label = "A, B, or C?",
                        choices = c(
                          Choose = '',
                          A = 'a',
                          B = 'b',
                          C = 'c'
                        ),
                        selectize = FALSE
                      ),
                      
                      conditionalPanel(
                        condition = "input.input1 !== ''",
                        selectInput(
                          inputId = "input2",
                          label = "D, or E?",
                          choices = c(Choose = '',
                                      D = 'd',
                                      E = 'e'),
                          selectize = FALSE
                          
                        )
                      ),
                      conditionalPanel(
                        condition = "input.input2 !== ''",
                        
                        actionButton(
                          "button1",
                          "SUBMIT",
                          style = "background-color:#221B70;
                          color:#E0EB15;
                          border-color:#E61029;
                          border-style:double;
                          border-width:4px;
                          border-radius:50%;
                          font-size:19px;"
                        ),
                        DT::dataTableOutput("tbl1"),
                        
                        
                        conditionalPanel(
                          condition = "typeof input.tbl1_rows_selected  !== 'undefined' && input.tbl1_rows_selected.length > 0",
                          actionButton(
                            "button2",
                            "GENERATE TABLE",
                            style = "background-color:#221B70;
                            color:#E0EB15;
                            border-color:#E61029;
                            border-style:double;
                            border-width:4px;
                            border-radius:50%;
                            font-size:19px;"
                          )
                          ),
                        
                        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.button2 > 0",
                                         div(
                                           "Selected items:", DT::dataTableOutput("tbl2")
                                         ))
                          )
                        )
                      ))
      )
    ))
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$button1, {
      output$tbl1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        items
      }, selection = 'multiple',
      class = "display nowrap compact",
      extensions = 'Scroller',
      options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip'))
      
    })
    observeEvent(input$button2, {
      table <- items[input$tbl1_rows_selected,c(2,3,4)]
      output$tbl2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
       table
      })
      
    })
  }
  
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input$tbl1_rows_selected` is a single integer if only one row is selected, it is a vector if several rows are selected, and it is `NULL` if no row is selected. So the appropriate condition is

```
"input.tbl1_rows_selected !== null"
```

`input$button2` is always an integer. It is initialized to `0` and then it increments each time the button is pressed. The condition to check that the button has been pressed is then

```
"input.button2 > 0"
```

I don't see what you mean by "the table below the third button". I don't see any table below this button.

## EDIT

That does not work:

```
"input.tbl1_rows_selected !== null"
```

That works:

```
"input.tbl1_rows_selected.length > 0"
```

It seems that `input.tbl1_rows_selected` is an empty JavaScript array when `input$tbl1_rows_selected` is `NULL` in R. Otherwise it is a non-empty array

Comment: I was just now sniffing around the NULL and 0 conditions, but I had them switched on the buttons! Thanks for that.   The "div("Selected items:", textOutput("selected", inline = TRUE)" block should not be displayed until the "Generate Table" button is pressed.  I'm thinking that I'll have to move all of that to the server side in order to stop the div from displaying all the time?

Comment: @Steve Sorry I don't understand what you mean. If you do `"input.button2 > 0"` then the `div` should not be display until the button is pressed.

Comment: You are correct, (I had missed a parens) It does fix that.  But for some reason using null in rows_selected doesn't work. I'm missing something. I've tried NULL, null, 'NULL', 'null', "NULL", "null"...etc

Comment: @Steve You're right, that does not work. I have found a solution, see my edit.

Comment: Hmm, I must still be missing something. I have updated my code to my current working version. (The follow on tables work as expected now.) But the Submit button and Generate Table button are still being displayed at the same time.

Comment: @Steve Sorry I typed `dtable` instead of `tbl1`. I will edit to correct that.

Comment: Yep, I saw that. But even with that correction it still isn't working.  I did however find a solution that I don't quite understand. "typeof input.tbl1_rows_selected  !== 'undefined'" works.